# COM Surrogate Server Timeout

Tags: c++, com, atl, out-of-process

I have a Win32/MFC application that depends on two separate STA COM DLL servers that I created many years ago using C++/ATL. These are large DLL servers with multiple interfaces and are also successfully used in other contexts and client programs. Several years ago, I had to create 64-bit versions of these 32-bit servers, and my 32-bit MFC app needed to be able to use either the 32-bit or 64-bit version of the DLL COM server (chosen with a checkbox).

Because a 32-bit process can't load a 64-bit COM server DLL in-process, I worked around this by having the MFC app create the 64-bit servers in the system surrogate (DLLHOST.EXE) by replacing

```
CoCreateInstance(..., CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, ...)
```

with

```
CoCreateInstance(..., CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER | CLSCTX_ACTIVATE_64_BIT_SERVER, ...)
```

Some updates were required, like adding an interface to copy environment variables into the server process and set the server/surrogate's working directory (the surrogate starts in SYSTEM32), but the other interfaces were all remoteable. This all seems to work perfectly and I can now use the 32-bit and 64-bit servers interchangeably from the 32-bit app by flipping a switch.

There is, however, one problem that I haven't been able to solve: **making the surrogate quickly terminate when the client releases the last interface**. The surrogate hangs around for 3-5 seconds after all remote interfaces are released by the MFC client -- presumably an optimization, hoping the client will come back. If the MFC app re-launches the server with *CoCreateInstance()* during that 3-5 seconds, it reconnects to the same "dirty" surrogate.  The server code is not serially re-usable (it packages up many thousands of lines of legacy ANSI "C" code with lots of static variables) so reconnecting to the same instance is just not possible.

I worked around this several years ago by having the startup interface return a COM error code indicating the server is waiting to be recycled (better than a crash). However, the servers are launched when the end user presses a toolbar button in the MFC app, so this means the user gets a message like "wait a few seconds and try again". That works, but the bad part is that every fresh launch attempt resets the 3-5 second counter that keeps the surrogate from exiting. And impatient users are complaining. I'll add this all works perfectly in-process, with `CoFreeUnusedLibraries()` working as expected.

I tried a number of things already -- everything short of coding an `ExitProcess()` in the server, which seems inappropriate. There seems to be no way to tell the surrogate that the application is complete and should not wait for more connections. The MS documentation claims [omitting the **RunAs** attribute in the AppID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/registering-the-dll-server-for-surrogate-activation) might help (I had it set to **"Interactive User"**) but it didn't. It also mentions `REGCLS_SINGLUSE` but then says ["Do not set REGCLS_SINGLUSE or REGCLS_MULTIPLEUSE when you register a surrogate for DLL servers"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/combaseapi/ne-combaseapi-regcls) and ["REGCLS_SINGLUSE and REGCLS_MULTIPLEUSE should not be used for DLL servers loaded into surrogates."](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/writing-a-custom-surrogate) and I don't have control over what the surrogate's class factory as far as I know.

It looks like COM+ might provide some control over recycling, as it seems to have a *RecycleActivationLimit* option that I might be able to set to 0, but I have no idea what it would take to convert this into a COM+ server.

The other possibility is to write a custom surrogate.

If there's no easy answer, I might just resort to greying out the button until the server vanishes -- but since I can't probe the server without extending its lifetime, I guess I could add a shared mutex and wait for it to vanish. Ugh.

Is RecycleActivationLimit somehow available to regular COM applications?  Any other suggestions are most welcome.

Comment: There is an easy answer: you should use COM+ Component Services. In a "server" mode, it's also a surrogate hosted by dllhost.exe. There should be no differences with what you have today, except you can configure lots of things using UI or scriptable COM objects, like "ShutdownAfter": https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cossdk/applications#shutdownafter also called "Enable idle shutdown" in the UI ("Advanced tab" of the application configuration)